# Can I use autocomplete to add users in a webform (they might be existing contacts)?

Tags: drupal, profile, webform-civicrm

I want to provide a screen for users to add some information about contacts (including custom info). Some of the contacts will be existing contacts, but some will be new. An autocomplete box would be ideal, similar to that used for creating a new contribution.  It doesn't appear that this is possible for profiles.  Can it be done with Webform-CiviCRM?  I am using Drupal.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it can be done with webforms. 
Select a 2nd contact in the *CiviCRM tab*, check **Existing Contact** and add any other fields that you want to expose on the form (including the custom info). Click **Save Settings**.

Go to the Webform tab and click on the field that was created for the Existing Contact. There you can set the autocomplete option for the Form Widget (in the **Display** area):
[image: Form Widget: Autocomplete]

Take note of the permissions setting in the **Filters** area as well so you don't end up exposing a lot of personal information unintentionally.

Comment: Thanks, I played around with this and in fact you need add only one 'existing' contact and that contact can be configured for auto-completion. And that, in turn, can handle adding new contacts.